# Problema con react-native run-android en Linux

Tags: react-native

---Ambiente--------------

S.O: Linux deepin 15.5

Node: 8.11.4

npm: 5.6.0

react-native-cli: 2.0

react-native: 0.56.0

emulador: Genymotion

---

Despripción del problema:

Intento ejecutar una aplicación para android con el comando `react-native run-android` y se muestra error que se muestra en la captura de pantalla.
[image: Error que se obtiene al ejecutar comando react-native run-android]

Cualquier sugerencia para solucionar el error será de gran utilidad.

Comment: Hola Josh, puede ser que estés usando un proxy?

Answer (score 0):

De hecho si estuve usando un proxy.

Los errores que se me mostraban eran producto de que no se descargaban correctamente las dependencias de Internet. Se solucionaron los errores una vez configuré correctamente el acceso a internet.